# Audio is being played from ear speaker on iOS Web App after using the microphone

Tags: ios, react-native, audio

We are developing aweb app where users can record their voice and play an audio response from a chatbot.

When we play the audio file at first, we can clearly hear it from the iOS device from the bottom speaker. After the user records and sends an audio message, from thereon and only on iOS, the audio response from the chatbot is played from the ear speaker, and we can hardly hear the sound since the volume is too low.

We are using the native browser's function to play sound:

```
const audio = new Audio("https://link to sound file")
audio.play()
```

And using 'react-audio-analyser' node module to record user's voice.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-audio-analyser

Has anyone encountered this issue?